# Jquery not focusing on the correct fields

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to have the focus in my isbn text box or the edition text boxafter running a calculation in jquery, but instead it is going to the first button on the page or the sales rank field.

My html is:

```
    <td><label>ISBN</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="isbn" name="isbn" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td rowspan=7><a id="detailURL" href="#" target="_blank"><img id="bookCover" src="../images/imgNotFound.gif" height="200px" /></a></td>
                <td rowspan=7><input type="button" id="isIE" name="isIE" value="IE Price Reduction" />
                    <br/><br/><input type="button" id="isAIE" name="isAIE" value="AIE Price Reduction" />
                    <br/><br/><input type="button" id="isModHighlight" name="isModHighlight" value="Moderate Highlighting" />
                    <br/><br/><input type="button" id="isHeavHighlight" name="isHeavHighlight" value="Heavy Highlighting" />
                    <br/><br/><input type="button" id="isMissingSupply" name="isMissingSupply" value="Missing Supply" />
                    <br /><br/><input type="button" id="waterDamage" name="waterDamage" value="Water Damage / Poor Cond." />
                </td>
                <td rowspan=7>
                    <!-- SUPPLY CHECK TABLE -->
                    <table id="supply" summary="Check Supply" width="10%" border="1" align="right">
                    <caption><h3>Check Supply!</h3></caption>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="rounded-isbn">Supply:</th>
                        <!--<th scope="col" class="rounded-isbn">Who Requires:</th>-->
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="quantity" class="label">Quantity</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="payPrice" class="label">Price to Pay</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="payPrice" name="payPrice"/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Edition</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="edition" name="edition" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Title</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="title" name="title" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Sales Rank</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="salesRank" name="salesRank" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td></td><td><input type="button" id="buy" value="Buy" /></td><td></td>
    </table>
    </form>
```

The jquery in question is:

```
if($('#payPrice').val() <= 0 ) {
    $(':text')[0].focus();
} else {
    $("#edition").focus();
}
```

When the value of `#payPrice` is `<=0`, it is defaulting to the first button `id="isIE"` and not the `isbn` field. If the value of `#payprice` is `>0` it is focusing on the sales rank text area, and not edition.  I have tried setting a timeout, which did not work as well as `$("#isbn).focus();`, which didn't work either.  I changed it to `$(':text')[0].focus();` to see if that would work, but it still went to the first button.
What am I doing wrong here?  How do I correct this to make it work as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final outcome, thanks to JackTurky who pointed me in the right direction.

```
    //focus on either isbn or edition
        setTimeout(function() {
            if($('#payPrice').val() <= 0 ) {
                    $("#isbn").focus();
                } else {
                    $("#edition").focus();
                }
                }, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
if(parseFloat($('#payPrice').val()) <= 0 ) {
...
}
```

if parseFloat make no difference try this:

```
if($('#payPrice').val()<=0){
   $("input[name='isbn']").focus(); 
}else{
   $("input[name='edition']").focus(); 
}
```

otherwise you could see that example:

```
function sampledFunction()
{
 window.setTimeout(function ()
 {
  $('#mobileno').focus();
 }, 0);
 return false;
}
```

read [here](http://antiarti.blogspot.it/2011/09/jquery-focus-function-not-working-in.html)

Comment: Adding in parseFloat did not make a difference, it still is focusing on the wrong items.  Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a better selector:

like `$('[type=text]')` or `$('input:text')`

See: [jQuery text selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)